# Forwarding Promises results in Promise chain - why I get Promise object instead of rejected value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a problem with understanding how forwarding promise results (nesting promises) works.

This code works as I expected (in final then I get integer value):

```js
function opThatResolves() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

function opThatWillBeForwarded(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(yetAnotherNestedPromise(x));
  })
}

function yetAnotherNestedPromise(x) {
  return Promise.resolve(-x);
}

opThatResolves()
  .then(x => opThatWillBeForwarded(x))
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => console.log("Resolved: " + x))
  .catch(x => console.log("Rejected: " + x))
```

So I thought that if I change `resolve` to `reject` I'll get similar result (integer value but without double *2 multipliation) in catch block. However I get a full `Promise` object:

```js
function opThatResolves() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

function opThatWillBeForwarded(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject(yetAnotherNestedPromise(x));
  })
}

function yetAnotherNestedPromise(x) {
  return Promise.resolve(-x);
}

opThatResolves()
  .then(x => opThatWillBeForwarded(x))
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => console.log("Resolved: " + x))
  .catch(x => console.log("Rejected: " + x))
```

Why `reject` does not "unwrap" Promise returned from `yetAnotherNestedPromise` just like `resolve` did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not supposed to receive a `Promise` in the first place.

The `reject` callback should contain a **reason** for having failed (ie, an `Error`).

```
function opThatResolves() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}

function opThatWillBeForwarded(x) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reject(new Error("failed"));
  })
}

opThatResolves()
  .then(x => opThatWillBeForwarded(x))
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => x * 2)
  .then(x => console.log("Resolved: " + x))
  .catch(x => console.log("Rejected: " + x));
```

Note that the error can be rethrown by subsequent error callbacks:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error("failed !"));
})
    .then(null, reason => {
        console.log(1, reason);
        throw reason;
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(2, reason);
    });
```

Also note that if an error callback fails to rethrow the error (or throw another error), the subsequent `then` methods will launch their success callbacks:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(new Error("failed !"));
})
    .then(null, reason => {
        console.log(1, reason);
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Success! Let's throw something else...");
        throw new Error("Another failure");
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(2, reason);
    });
```